# Active Record connect to SQL Server 2008 says no known event listeners

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate, activerecord

I try to connet to SQL SERVER 2008 using active record and I get:
Failed to initialize ActiveRecords! ---> System.ArgumentException: The Listener of type .... does not implement any known NHibernate event listener interfaces.

Is this some problem in my business object declaration? It works well with other databases, Oracle, SQLite, etc...

```
<activerecord isWeb="false" isDebug="false">
      <config>
        <add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
        <add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect" />
        <add key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
        <add key="connection.connection_string" value="Data Source=SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=HFPMDB;User ID=db_owner;Password=HFPMAdmin;" />
        <add key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle" />
      </config>
    </activerecord>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I added an extra assembly to the "ActiveRecordAssemblies".
The assembly did not contain any Active Record attributes and etc, so that was the reason.